# how to get closed dropdown of hamburger menu when an option has been selected in Shiny

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, shiny, navbar

I have a collapsible navbar menu in R Shiny. When the menu has collapsed and I click on the Hamburger button, the options appear. When I click on one of the options, another panel is (rightly) chosen, but the menu stays open.

Is it possible to make it so (with css?) that the 'dropdown menu' (i.e. list of options) closes as soon as I have chosen one of the options?

The code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
  navbarPage(
    title = NULL, id = "navBar", collapsible = TRUE,

    tabPanel(title = "Panel1", uiOutput('panel1')),
    tabPanel(title = "Panel2", uiOutput('panel2')),
    tabPanel(title = "Panel3", uiOutput('panel3'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$panel1 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 1")})
  output$panel2 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 2")})
  output$panel3 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 3")})
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: are you sure your code example matches the question? I dont see a dropdown menu running your code,...

Comment: No, maybe 'dopdown menu' is not the right term. But when making  the browser window narrow, the navbar menu is reduced to a Hamburger button. When clicking on this, a kind of dropdown menu appears. This 'dropdown menu' should disappear when the user has chosen one of the options (in the code: 'Panel1', 'Panel2' or 'Panel3').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen on the navbarPage with `input$navBar` (your id in  `navbarPage()`) and trigger the changes via javascript.

```
  observeEvent(input$navBar, {
    runjs('
      var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-collapse")[0]
      elem.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
      elem.setAttribute("class", "navbar-collapse collapse");
    ')
  })
```

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- tagList(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(
    title=NULL, id = "navBar", collapsible = TRUE,

    tabPanel(title = "Panel1", uiOutput('panel1')),
    tabPanel(title = "Panel2", uiOutput('panel2')),
    tabPanel(title = "Panel3", uiOutput('panel3'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$panel1 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 1")})
  output$panel2 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 2")})
  output$panel3 <- renderUI({p("This is panel 3")})

  observeEvent(input$navBar, {
    runjs('
      var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-collapse")[0]
      elem.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
      elem.setAttribute("class", "navbar-collapse collapse");
    ')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```